# sqlite, how replace a value from CSV saved in a column

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, replace, rename

I have a table in my android app with a column named tags, this column can contain one or multiple comma separated values, for example :

`test1,test,test2`

now I want to rename one of these values in entire table, I have the following query :

```
update mytable
set 
    tags = replace (tags, ',test,',',XXX,') // rename test with XXX
where
    tags like '%,test,%'
```

this works fine as far as the value is in between commas.

How can I achieve this for the situation where my value is at the start or end of the csv or is the only value in csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append commas at the start and at the end of the column and operate on that:

```
update mytable
set 
    tags = trim(replace(',' || tags || ',', ',test,', ',XXX,'), ',')
where
    ',' || tags || ',' like '%,test,%';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPLEtX5yxGcEAo8xta6k4/0)